# How do you implement, firebase completion this source

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I want to get a firebase token and store it as a String variable. I tried with the source code below but it doesn't work.

How can I store and use the token value I obtained as a string?

It works well with firebase and if you load and print from the same class you can see the token value is printed out right away.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseInstanceID

class MyGetFirebaseToken{
    func getFirebaseToken(completion: @escaping (String) -> String){
        var returnString: String = ""

        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
            if let result = result {
                returnString = result.token
                print("MY Token:::" + returnString)
            } else {
                returnString = "ERROR"
                print("Firebase Get Token ERROR: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
        completion(returnString)
    }
}
```

I expect the output "QWEQWEQ231....ASDAS6", but Returns a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

> completion(returnString) this line should be instanceID block like below.

```
func getFirebaseToken(completion: @escaping (String) -> String){
    var returnString: String = ""

    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
        if let result = result {
            returnString = result.token
            print("MY Token:::" + returnString)
        } else {
            returnString = "ERROR"
            print("Firebase Get Token ERROR: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        completion(returnString)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, Your coment is very good idea, But i called another class ' let myToken = MyGetFirebaseToken().getFirebaseToken()'... that's result error...

Comment: @프로꾸 hey I am not giving you idea there is issue in your code you have write completion outside of firebase api. so when you call its directly return empty string.